# Php Json Get inside array

Tags: php, json

This is My json How can get "download" string

```
{
"total": 1,
"items": [
 {
  "id": "1186e1472bc1c",
  "title": "title,
  "desc": "",
  "download": "www.google.com",
   }
  ]
}
```

This is My code:

```
$response = file_get_contents($nagu);
$obj = json_decode($response, true);
$download = $obj ['items'];
echo $download;
```

I want output "www.google.com".

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Comment: By the way, you have two syntax errors in your JSON string. To fix them: firstly add a double quotation mark at the end of line 6 before the `,` and then remove the last `,` in line 8 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$download = $obj ['items'][0]['download'];
echo $download;
```